# correlation between two categorical variables in R

Tags: r

I have been trying to calculate the correlation between two categorical variables (level of education, political party voted) in R. I found that I could use Pearson chi-sq test. I applied it and got some results, and I wonder whether it is a true method or not.
Also, how can I visualize my results for that Pearson test in R?
Thx in advance. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42uXJ.png)

Comment: You would normally use [Mosaic Plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_plot)

Comment: Do you think Pearson chi-sq is proper method for that kind of variables? Or is there any better statistical method to apply?

Comment: Chi squared is fine

Comment: The chi-square test is a measure of independence not a measure of the strength of an association. The table seems large since the degrees of freedom is (rows - 1) * (cols - 1) you either have an 8x8 table or a 2x50 table. Cramer's V, Lambda, and Uncertainty measures are possible and available in the `DescTools` package.

Comment: yes, basically I have 8 choices for education and 8 choices for political parties. So, do you think that using Cramer's V, Lambda, and Uncertainty measures fits better for these variables?

Comment: This is not a programming question for StackOverflow Please ask your statistal testing question on Stats.StackExchange.com